# What would be preventing the second SMS from being sent via the API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm using an API to send SMS messages to a small group of people.

I wrapped the API call into a function, so that it can be called like this:

```
sendSMS($number, "Message goes here")
```

The function itself is also fairly simple.

```
function sendSMS($dst, $msg){
if(!$dst || !$msg){
    exit();
}

$params = array();
$params['api_username'] = "USERNAME";
$params['api_password'] = "PASSWORD";
$params['method'] = "sendSMS";
$params['dst'] = getCleanPhone($dst); // Custom number validation/formatting
$params['message'] = $msg;
$params['did'] = "5555551212"; // Our real outgoing SMS number, replaced for this example


// Use curl to send your message
$c = curl_init('https://example.net/api/v1/rest.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$response = json_decode($result,true);   
// For debugging, I'm logging $response
}
```

If I call this function once, the message is sent as expected. However, if I call it twice in a row, only the first message is sent. For example,

```
    sendSMS($number, "Message1 goes here") // This gets sent successfully
    sendSMS($number, "Message2 goes here") // This doesn't get sent
```

I checked with the API provider and there's nothing on their end that would prevent this from working as expected. Is there something in this code, or a setting on the server, that would be preventing the second message from being sent?

**EDIT**
If I return true/false based on the APR response, like this:

```
if($response['status']=='success'){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

And then chain the function calls together like this,

```
    if(sendSMS($number, "Message1 goes here"){
       sendSMS($number, "Message2 goes here");
    }
```

Then it seems to work as expected. What would be the reason that the function can't be called twice in a row without chaining them together if they're just sending an API call?

Comment: what does the response say?

Comment: @OMiShah it comes back 'success' for the first one, but nothing is logged for the second one as if it's not called at all.

Comment: Run `var_dump(curl_getinfo($c));` after the `curl_exec()` to see the response headers and other handy info.

Comment: try adding print statements between lines and check if the method is called and those lines are executed. But, most probably something is wrong with your API service provider.

Comment: You're probably being rate limited and you're getting a 429 response with no body. At the very least, you need to check the CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE to get the response status.

Comment: Added an edit, not sure if you'd understand why this function is working this way.

Comment: Try putting a `usleep()` between  requests.  If `usleep(1000)` works, reduce the 1000µS to 500µS.  Keep reducing until you get the magic number.